# Add-Content to CSV Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, append

When I run the below code I get a list of details in separate columns.

```
$file = 'c:\output\testing.csv'
   Get-AdUser -filter "DisplayName -eq 'joe bloggs'" | 
   Get-ADUser -Properties * |  
 Select-Object givenName, surname, mail, 
@{ Label = "Country"
Expression = { if ($_.Country) { $_.Country } else { "GB" } }
 ,samaccountname, department, description | Export-csv -path $file
```

Output (1) is as follows:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------------+------------+-------------+
| givenName | surname |      mail       | Country | samaccountname | department | description |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------------+------------+-------------+
| joe       | bloggs  | joe.b@email.com | GB      | bloggsG        | IT         | Support     |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

However, if I amend the Export-CSV to `Add-Content`, the output (2) is as below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+------------+-------------+
|                                                               givenName                                                               | surname | mail | Country | samaccountname | department | description |
| {givenName=Fred; surname=Smith; mail=fred.s@email.com; Country=GB; samaccountname=smithF; department=Facilities; description=cleaner} |         |      |         |                |            |             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

How do I use `Add-Content` to show the same output as the first table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) is for appending unstructured text to a *text file*, similar to `Set-Content` - you cannot use it to append rows to an existing *CSV file*.

Instead, you must **use `Export-Csv -Append`**:

```
... | Export-Csv -Path $file -Append -Encoding Ascii # pick the proper encoding
```

**Character-encoding caveats**, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1<sup>[1]</sup>:

- *Without* `-Append`, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) uses **ASCII**(!) encoding - against documented behavior.

  - This means that non-ASCII characters are transliterated to *literal* `?`, i.e., you may *lose information*.
- *With* `-Append`, curiously, non-ASCII characters are **UTF-8**-encoded - irrespective of the file's original encoding.

**To get predictable behavior, always use `-Encoding` explicitly with `Export-Csv` - both with and without `-Append`.**

---

<sup>[1] The cross-platform PowerShell *Core* edition is not affected, because it consistently uses BOM-less UTF-8 encoding by default.</sup>