# Get SamAccountName from text file with DisplayNames

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, character-encoding

I got a Script that works, but since we have coworker which have ö,ü,ä in their names the csv resolves them into ? (Example: Hörnlima = H?rnlima). Because of this it doesn't give me back any SamAccountname and the list isn't correct anymore. How can I correct that?

Script:

```
Import-Csv D:\Files\PowerShell\Test\4ME\DisplaynameToSamAccountName\Displaynames.txt | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName | 
Select Name,SamAccountName
} | Export-CSV -path D:\Files\PowerShell\Test\4ME\DisplaynameToSamAccountName\Accountnames.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your CSV is saved in UTF8 encoding. Then use `Import-Csv -Path .. -Encoding UTF8`. Save with `Export-Csv -Path .. -Encoding UTF8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Use, e.g., `Export-Csv -Encoding utf8 ...` to save your file with [UTF-8 character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which ensures that accented characters such as `ö` are preserved.

---

**In *Windows PowerShell*, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) regrettably defaults to ASCII encoding**, which means that **any characters outside the US-ASCII range - notably *accented* characters such as `ö` - are transliterated to *literal* `?`**.

That is, such characters are *lost*, because they cannot be represented in ASCII encoding.

In **PowerShell [Core] v6+**, *all* cmdlets, including `Export-Csv`, now thankfully **default to BOM-less UTF-8 encoding**.

As for the behavior when you *append* to a preexisting CSV file with the `-Append` switch without specifying `-Encoding`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52866494/45375).

---

Therefore, especially in Windows PowerShell, **use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify the desired character encoding**:

- **`-Encoding utf8` is advisable**, because it is capable of encoding *all* Unicode characters.

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, the resulting file will *invariably* have a BOM.
  - In *PowerShell [Core] v6+*, it will be BOM-less, which is generally better for cross-platform compatibility, but you can alternatively use `-Encoding utf8BOM` to use a BOM.
- **`-Encoding Unicode` ([UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)LE)** encoding is another option, but results in larger files (most characters are encodes by *2* bytes). This encoding *always* results in a BOM.
- **`-Encoding Default`** (Windows PowerShell) or
  `-Encoding (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ANSICodePage` (PowerShell [Core] v6+) on Windows uses **your system's active ANSI [code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)** to create a BOM-less file.

  - **This legacy encoding is *best avoided*, however**, for multiple reasons:

    - Many modern applications assume UTF-8 encoding in the absence of a BOM.
    - Even those that read the file as ANSI-encoded may interpret a file differently if the host system happens to have a *different* active ANSI page.
    - Since the active ANSI code page is (for Western cultures) a fixed, single-byte encoding, only 256 characters can be represented, which is only a small subset of all Unicode characters.

---

Note that **when PowerShell *reads* a file that is BOM-less**, including source code, the behavior differs between the two editions:

- In **Windows PowerShell**, `Default` is assumed, i.e. the system's **active ANSI code page**.

  - Note that in recent versions of Windows 10 it is now possible to make UTF-8 the ANSI code page, but such a system-wide change can have unintended consequences - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).
- In **PowerShell [Core] v6+**, **UTF-8** is assumed.